# WebService hangs while loading VB6 legacy interop

Tags: .net, iis, dll, com, vb6

We have two dll's - one x.dll (legacy DLL built with Visual C/C++ 2005 and Visual Basic 6), another x.Interop.dll generated with tlbimp.
x.Interop.dll added as a reference and is used by our webservice.

While using .NET ASMX application there are two calls to it:

- **First** - checks if service is available and provides which data is available to query
- **Second** - starts using x.Interop.dll and queries the data.

Second query does not pass and hangs while loading interop.

Some interesting facts:

1. It does not work only on deployment server (IIS 8.5) while it works on
   development machine (IIS 10). On both server same msi package installed.
2. It is possible to reproduce same issue on development machine by
   renaming or removing access to x.dll. However, in event viewer it
   writes warning or error that service does not have access to it,
   while deployment server does not says anything about accessing
   x.dll.
3. Tried various various configurations on Component Security settings and nothing seems to be helpful.
4. 32-bit Applications are obviously enabled on web-service.
5. Wrote a separate console exe application with x.Interop.dll with simple initialization and call (like we doing it on web-service) and it worked on both machines.

Comment: Few items to check - is it a new version of the interop? Is it possible you have a cached version of this file?  With it working in a console app it could be an issue with something in the security.  Try messing around with the user that runs the app - which .net pipeline? It could be that the user can't read the registry to read the com registration or it reads the old value.   Have you tested on other machines to validate if it is single machine weirdness?